# Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

As part of Spring Security, recently I upgraded my project from **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** to **SecurityFilterChain as a Bean**. I'm trying to use as much available resources as I can from the documentation, but I dont know what I'm doing wrong. It says **This object has already been built**, but I don't know how to fix it.

**Configuration class:**

```
package com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.configuration;

import com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("Marcelo")
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build());

        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("john")
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                .password("1234")
                .roles("USER", "MANAGER")
                .build());

        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("will")
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                .password("1234")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build());

        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("jim")
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                .password("1234")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build());

        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("arnold")
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                .password("1234")
                .roles("SUPER_ADMIN")
                .build());

        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST)
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SUPER_ADMIN")

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET)
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "MANAGER")

                .and()
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class))));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        return auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/github/marceloasfilho/wallet/configuration/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.WalletApplication.main(WalletApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.beforeConfigure(HttpSecurity.java:3209) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:302) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.configuration.SecurityConfiguration.filterChain(SecurityConfiguration.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.configuration.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2383da.CGLIB$filterChain$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.configuration.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2383da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b6e723e1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.github.marceloasfilho.wallet.configuration.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2383da.filterChain(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 23 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `return http.build()` try,
`return http.getOrBuild();`