# Adding JWT filter to filter chain throws 'This object has already been built' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I use Spring Boot 3 and have the following issue.

This is my `filterChain` method:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .addFilter(new JwtUserNameAndPasswordAuthFilter(authManager(http)))
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    return http.build();
}
```

And this is the `authManager` method:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http
                                .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
}
```

Now, with this setup, I get the error

> Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: This object has already been built

If I remove the JWT filter, it works. I assume, because I let build the `AuthenticationManager` and in the `filterChain` method there is another build.

How to resolve this issue under Spring Boot 3? In the `filterChain` method I need the build, since the method has to return a `SecurityFilterChain`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187035/error-creating-bean-with-name-filterchain-org-springframework-security-config) question, which is exactly my problem, but unfortunatelly, there is no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching deeper on the net, I found the answer based on [this](https://blog.devgenius.io/implementing-authentication-and-authorization-using-spring-security-kotlin-and-jwt-an-easy-and-cc82a1f20567) blog post.

In the `filterChain` method I declared an `authManager` like this:

```java
AuthenticationManager authManager = authManager(http);
```

Then I modified the security config like this:

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authenticationManager(authManager)
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .addFilter(new JwtUserNameAndPasswordAuthFilter(authManager))
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Now, it builds.